# Knit/rmarkdown problem managing private data files

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I’m using RStudio with `rmarkdown`/`bookdown`, then `git` to publish to Github Pages, and specifically into a `./docs` dir in the repo. The repo has to necessarily be a private one, though there is no sensitive information in the knitted output. I’m achieving the correct separation of code and output by setting a YAML option

Everything seems to work fine, except for one (big) problem. The `.Rmd` file reads from `.xls(x)` files, and they’re both in the root dir of the repo.

My main problem is that whenever I knit the `.Rmd` file, not only does it output the relevant `html` file to the `./docs` subdir, but it also seems to copy the Excel files which are meant to be private.

To my understanding, code execution should start and end in the root dir, then the knitted file should be written to the ouput dir. I don’t see why source data (used in a few calls to `readxl::read_excel()`) should be moved around together with the output.

Can anyone please help me understand?Thanks!

Comment: What functions are you using to render your project? I have had success with the function `render_site()` which is actually in the *Rmarkdown* package. and you could also use `rmarkdown::render()` which takes in individual files(.Rmd) which I would hope wouldn't copy your .xlsx files

Comment: Hi and thanks for your interest. I’m using vanilla `rmakrdown::render()` as provided by the glorious Knit button in Rstudio 